# Update pattern with path line selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use the enter(), update(), exit() pattern for a line chart, and I'm not getting my lines to appear properly.

A fiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/wy6h1jcg/

THey do show up in the dom, but have no x or y values (though they are styled)

My svg is already created as follows:

```
var chart = d3.select("#charts")
              .append("svg")
chart
    .attr("width", attributes.chartsWidth)
    .attr("height", attributes.chartsHeight);
```

I want to create a new object for my update binding, as follows:

```
var thechart = chart.selectAll("path.line").data(data, function(d){return d.x_axis} )

        thechart.enter()
            .append("path")


        thechart.transition().duration(100).attr('d', line).attr("class", "line");
```

But this is no good.

Note, this does work (but can't be used for our update):

```
chart.append("path")
      .datum(data, function(d){return d.x_axis})
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

One other note:

I have a separate function that binds data for creating another chart on the svg.

```
var thechart = chart.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data, function(d){return d.x_axis});

              thechart.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class","bars")
```

Could these two bindings be interacting?

Comment: I notice that you're using *datum* rather than *data*.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: I use datum in my example but it's not consistent with an update pattern. You can't form joins with datum

Comment: That was where I was going.  Can you post a working example in a fiddle or similar?  In the meantime [this](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/10277224) example might point you in the right direction.

Comment: fddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wy6h1jcg/

Comment: What sort of transition effect are you after?  The way that the line function works is that you pass the series of coordinates and it returns a svg line.  So, if you want to transition to a new line the data you pass to the line generator will need to be an array of coordinate.  The way you've set it up, you are passing each coordinate pair to the line function not an array of coordinates which doesn't give you the results you are after.

Comment: I want to add the chart with one update, then set its values (with d.percent) to 0 with another. THe dataset is setup to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61357/discussion-between-in-code-veritas-and-user1614080).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the update logic I ended on, still a closured pattern:

```
function updateScatterChart(chartUpdate) {

        var wxz = (wx * 37) + c;

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([c, wxz]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([h, hTopMargin]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(+d.x_axis); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(+d.percent); }).interpolate("basis");

        if (lastUpdateLine != chartUpdate) {
            console.log('updating..')
            d3.csv("./data/multiline.csv", function(dataset) {


                console.log(chartUpdate);

                var data2 = dataset.filter(function(d){return d.type == chartUpdate});


                x.domain(d3.extent(data2, function(d) { return +d.x_axis; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data2, function(d) { return +d.percent; })]);

                var thechart2 = chart.selectAll("path.line").data(data2, function(d){return d.neighborhood;});

                    thechart2.enter()
                    .append("svg:path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", line(data2))


               thechart2.transition()
                    .duration(800)
                    .attr("d", line(data2))
                    .style("opacity", (chartUpdate == 'remove') ? 0 : 1 )

                thechart2.exit()
                    .transition()
                    .duration(400)
                    .remove();


              })
        }
        lastUpdateLine = chartUpdate;

}
```